# To obtain names of 3 highest records in the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df as shown below:

```
    City Name        Division   Population
1   California       A          100
2   Texas            B          98
3   NewYork          C          96
4   Florida          D          94
5   Illinois         E          92
6   Pennsylvania     F          90
7   Ohio             G          88
8   Michigan         H          86
9   Georgia          I          84
10  North Carolina   J          82
```

I would like to write a code to obtain the 3 most populous cities as string values.

Desired output:

```
 ['California', 'Texas', 'NewYork']
```

How can i do this??

Comment: This site is intended to be a database of questions and answers for programmers who may be stuck on a particular technical problem. Your question appears to be more of a "I need to write some code to perform this task, but I don't know where to start". It's very specific, and unlikely to help others in the future. This, unfortunately, is not a good fit for SO. Please may I suggest that you take a look at [ask]. If you have already made an attempt at coding this yourself, then please show your efforts and tell us how it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print (df.nlargest(3, 'Population')['City Name'].tolist())
['California', 'Texas', 'NewYork']
```

If data are sorted in column `Population` use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
print (df['City Name'].iloc[:3].tolist())
['California', 'Texas', 'NewYork']
```

---

```
print (df['City Name'].head(3).tolist())
['California', 'Texas', 'NewYork']
```